# .htaccess redirect everything to https non-www and 404 to index

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I was trying to use .htaccess to redirect any request to https non-www and every 404 to index (previous rules included). This is the end result, but it doesn't work as intended. What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
ErrorDocument 404 https://mydomain.com/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://mydomain.com/
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://mydomain.com/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```

The above will redirect all non-https to https and then if the file doesn't exist it is redirect to the index.